# Layering with slopes in Unity 2D isometric scene

Tags: unity, 2d, isometric, depth

I'm newer to Unity so bear with me. I'm using `Unity2D` and so far I have my character up and walking around, colliding properly with his surroundings, and I've implemented an effective `"isometric sorting"` script which swaps the order of sprites based on their y coordinate. What I'm trying to do now is create a slope that exists in the middle of the stage or front (bottom of screen). I'll illustrate what I'm trying to do as explaining it is bound to be confusing.

[image: Here is what I'm hoping to achieve.]

Right now, I have the ability to move the player up the slope, and in front of the slope (using the isometric sorting script), but it seems maybe impossible to *also* be able to have the player walk behind the slope.

Here's my idea for how this could be accomplished, but I certainly would need some direction.

[image]

Basically, I'm thinking if I can detect that the player has crossed the green line in the image, I could use that information to flip a switch ON which would lower the slopes sorting priority (thus lowering it beneath the players feet), then I would need it to deactivate when the Player exits the slope.

Here is the Isometric Rendering script:

```
    using UnityEngine;

    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class IsometricSpriteRenderer : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update ()
    {
         GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingOrder = (int)(transform.position.y *       -1000);
    }
}
```

Thank you to anyone who bothers to take the time to help me! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Why not just add a "z" value to each item in your isometric game? Higher y gets priority in sorting. The same y yields sorting based on the highest z.

Comment: Thanks for the response, DMGregory. I'm going to see if I can come up with a way to make that work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a wrong approach. Check this tutorial: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/sorting-layers

In order to sort your stuff properly and automatically you can use depth (*z*) and/or sorting layers within objects at the same depth and/or order in layer within objects in the same sorting layer. It's probably reasonable to have objects representing fixed features of the game world (like the slope) use fixed depth/layer/order and have objects representing moveable features of the game world (like the characters) use variable depth/layer/order.

Keep colliders for actual collisions.